# No such module 'FirebaseMessaging' - after adding Firebase SDK manually

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, swift-package-manager

I am trying to make a push Notification Service package for app. So now Im trying to import FirebaseMessaging package to my Swift package manually. But it show an error - "No such module 'FirebaseMessaging'" while trying to import FirebaseMessaging.

So what is the reason ? I have included my Package.swift file bellow :-

```
// swift-tools-version: 5.7
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
name: "PNServieDemo",
products: [
    // Products define the executables and libraries a package produces, and make them visible to other packages.
    .library(
        name: "PNServieDemo",
        targets: ["PNServieDemo"]),
],
dependencies: [
    .package(path: "Sources/FirebaseMessaging")
    // Dependencies declare other packages that this package depends on.
    // .package(url: /* package url */, from: "1.0.0"),
],
targets: [
    // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
    // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages this package depends on.
    .target(
        name: "PNServieDemo",
        dependencies: [.product(name: "FirebaseMessaging", package: "FirebaseMessaging")]),
    .testTarget(
        name: "PNServieDemoTests",
        dependencies: ["PNServieDemo"]),
]
)
```

[Screenshoot here - Link 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bg2tI.png)
[Screenshoot here] - Link 2(https://ibb.co/bPK2cqx)

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you use `Pod` instead of `Package`.

```
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
```

I hope this will help.